# What does <Class *> do?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have seen Apple using this in their latest APIs:

```
NSArray <GKPlayer *>* players;
NSArray *players;
```

What does the  do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `players` is pointer to an array of pointers to `GKPlayer` objects.

Answer (score 1):

It is called generics. It's purpose is to define what is inside your collection types.

Read more here: http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/